# R data.frame(column1, column2) is acting like data.frame(column1, row1)

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I am writing R code to combine two vectors to create a dataframe so I can plot it.

[image]

So I run this code and this is the data frame I get:

[image]

The result I am going for is to instead have a second column called rates that corresponds to the three specified numbers. So, if I can `df$rates` it would return 62.96, 47.28, 24.24.

I feel like this should be relatively simple, but every solution that I have found says to do the what I am already doing, not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: Can you provide your data via `dput(rates)` and `dput(classes)`? You can edit your question and paste those in.

Comment: `classes<-as.factor(c("First","Second","Third")); 
firstRate<-62.96; 
secondRate<-47.28; 
thirdRate<-24.24; 
rates<-c(firstRate,secondRate,thirdRate); 
df<-data.frame(classes,rates); 
df ` does not reproduce your results but does what you may have hoped for

Comment: Seems like your `firstRate`, `secondRate`, and `thirdRate` are `list`s, not atomic vectors. But hard to tell from a picture of data, please share reproducible data as Andrew suggests.